# How can I print out all the contents of the stack at a specific point in time of a binary file execution?

Tags: assembly, scripting, stack, gdb

I just have a binary file, no source code whatsoever. I have disassembled it and have the assembly code, which shows that the program has a significant number of variables. I am trying to debug it in gdb, but would like to have an overview of all that is in the stack.

Specifically, I'd like to step through all of the memory between the top of the stack and the bottom of it at a particular point in time, printing out all of the content (of course this will include a lot of garbage) in this region and hopefully storing it in a file. Is there a way of doing this in gdb or otherwise?

*the 'p' command hasn't been useful here

Comment: x/0x100wx $rsp-0x100 or something like this. This could be a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233095/memory-dump-formatted-like-xxd-from-gdb.

Comment: Sorry. You need to write x/256wx...

Comment: What architecture and OS are you using? The way to find the bottom of the stack varies.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick x86-64 ubuntu linux

Comment: @dbrank0 thanks, the link  gave me ideas