# gdb python: turn expression into address

Tags: gdb, gdb-python

I want to get the address from a value in the same way that the `x` examine command works. Internally, this seems to use [`value_as_address`](https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/blob/master/gdb/value.c#L2684-L2688), which turns any gdb expression into a core address. I have not managed to find a binding for this anywhere in the Python API surface. Further, the workarounds I've seen so far don't seem to accomplish this:

- It is not reasonable to [cast the type to a void pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9237555/2350164) because this is language dependent (will not work in Rust executables, for instance):

  ```
  some_Value.cast(gdb.lookup_type('void').pointer())
  ```

  will fail if there is no "void" type, as in the case of Rust.
- I want to accept integers, which should come out unchanged.

In particular, I want a function that takes strings such as `"0x5555555740a0"`, `"main"`,  etc and turns them into an integer containing their address.

Comment: If you just want the address as integer, doesn't `int(gdb.parse_and_eval(some_string))` do that?

Comment: I think so, yes, thanks! I still need to test fully, but it seems to work