# How to examine bytes in gdb without printing labels?

Tags: c++, c, gdb

GDB is trying to be helpful by labeling what I believe are global variables, but in this case each global is more than 0x10 bytes and so the second part of the variable is printed on the next line, but with an offset added to its label, which throws off the alignment of the whole printout (generated by executing `x/50wx 0x604130`):
[image: Unwanted offset in gdb labels]
Is there a command to disable these labels while examining bytes?

Edit: to be more specific, I would like to printout exactly what is shown in the screenshot, just without the `<n1>` / `<n1+16>` labels that are throwing off the alignment of the columns

Comment: There are various ways to get gdb to show the contents of memory. The question does not have sufficient information to be able to determine an alternative way to inspect these mysterious objects.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I just want to print out exactly what is shown in the screenshot, just without those <n33> <n33 + 16> labels

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text. Cut/paste text itself.

Comment: @EmployedRussian unfortunately I can't (or at least I don't know how) to copy/paste from tui. I'm not able to select text in that mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a command to disable these labels while examining bytes?

I don't believe there is.

One might expect that `set print symbol off` would do it, but it doesn't.

The closest I can suggest is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9234007/50617).